# Is it possible to convert JSON into a Data URI with PHP or JS?

Tags: php, javascript, json, data-uri

Is it possible to convert JSON into a Data URI with PHP or JS?

When I use Signature Pad by Thomas J Bradley (http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/) to collect electronic / digital signatures through HTML5 Canvas, I get the following JSON output:

> [{"lx":27,"ly":4,"mx":27,"my":3},{"lx":27,"ly":5,"mx":27,"my":4},{"lx":25,"ly":33,"mx":27,"my":5},{"lx":25,"ly":32,"mx":25,"my":33},{"lx":28,"ly":7,"mx":28,"my":6},{"lx":30,"ly":5,"mx":28,"my":7},{"lx":31,"ly":5,"mx":30,"my":5},{"lx":32,"ly":5,"mx":31,"my":5},{"lx":38,"ly":5,"mx":32,"my":5},{"lx":41,"ly":5,"mx":38,"my":5},{"lx":42,"ly":5,"mx":41,"my":5},{"lx":43,"ly":5,"mx":42,"my":5},{"lx":42,"ly":6,"mx":43,"my":5},{"lx":40,"ly":7,"mx":42,"my":6},{"lx":37,"ly":8,"mx":40,"my":7},{"lx":29,"ly":13,"mx":37,"my":8},{"lx":25,"ly":16,"mx":29,"my":13},{"lx":26,"ly":16,"mx":25,"my":16},{"lx":30,"ly":16,"mx":26,"my":16},{"lx":31,"ly":16,"mx":30,"my":16},{"lx":32,"ly":16,"mx":31,"my":16},{"lx":33,"ly":16,"mx":32,"my":16},{"lx":34,"ly":16,"mx":33,"my":16},{"lx":36,"ly":16,"mx":34,"my":16},{"lx":32,"ly":18,"mx":36,"my":16},{"lx":30,"ly":18,"mx":32,"my":18},{"lx":28,"ly":20,"mx":30,"my":18},{"lx":27,"ly":20,"mx":28,"my":20},{"lx":27,"ly":22,"mx":27,"my":20},{"lx":29,"ly":22,"mx":27,"my":22},{"lx":30,"ly":22,"mx":29,"my":22},{"lx":32,"ly":22,"mx":30,"my":22},{"lx":35,"ly":22,"mx":32,"my":22},{"lx":61,"ly":9,"mx":61,"my":8},{"lx":60,"ly":8,"mx":61,"my":9},{"lx":59,"ly":8,"mx":60,"my":8},{"lx":58,"ly":8,"mx":59,"my":8},{"lx":54,"ly":11,"mx":58,"my":8},{"lx":52,"ly":12,"mx":54,"my":11},{"lx":51,"ly":14,"mx":52,"my":12},{"lx":51,"ly":15,"mx":51,"my":14},{"lx":50,"ly":18,"mx":51,"my":15},{"lx":49,"ly":24,"mx":50,"my":18},{"lx":49,"ly":25,"mx":49,"my":24},{"lx":50,"ly":26,"mx":49,"my":25},{"lx":52,"ly":27,"mx":50,"my":26},{"lx":55,"ly":28,"mx":52,"my":27},{"lx":56,"ly":28,"mx":55,"my":28},{"lx":57,"ly":29,"mx":56,"my":28},{"lx":59,"ly":29,"mx":57,"my":29}]

The JSON output could be used to redraw / regenerate an electronic / digital signature onto a HTML5 Canvas.

What I'm trying to accomplish is converting the JSON output into a Data URI.

If clarification or more information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Outputting a link with a `data:application/json,` prefix seems easy enough. How didn't it work?

Comment: Yes of course it's possible, but why would you want that? Embedding JSON in the source of other files ([what data URLs are made for](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)) is easy enough.

Comment: @mario can you show me?

Comment: @Bergi It's a weird request, but I'm trying to generate a data:uri to be included within an email, instead of showing the JSON output above, which would require visiting my website and regenerating their signature. With a data URI, you can just copy and paste it into the URL bar to view the signature.

Comment: @BowenCheng: Nope, you would just be able to see the raw JSON file. To view the signature, make a web page that accepts the JSON as an URL parameter (or hash value) and draws it. Then link that.

Comment: Are you asking for the code to create an image out of the JSON (onto the canvas) and then make a data-uri out of it?

Comment: @JuanMendes Yep! That's exactly it! Haha. Bergi's suggestion is alright, but that's what I want. Can you show me how to do just that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking how to draw an image using your JSON and then get a data uri for it.

You could use the following

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var jsonObj = [{x:1, y:2}, {x:3,x:4}];

  // draw using your data, you implement this
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(jsonObj[0].x, jsonObj[0].y);
  context.moveTo(jsonObj[1].x, jsonObj[1].y);
  context.closePath();
  context.lineWidth = 5;
  context.fillStyle = '#8ED6FF';
  context.fill();
  context.strokeStyle = '#0000ff';
  context.stroke();

  // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  alert(dataURL);
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/D9e2u/

Comment: Is it possible to do this in PHP? The JSON output above is currently captured within a PHP variable ($output).

Comment: You asked for JS, now you want PHP? Make up your mind, I'm only posting the JS answer

Comment: @JuanMendes, you're at an 8. Take it down to a 2 or 3.  He was just asking.  Can we keep SO friendly, please? We want to encourage questions, not flames.  (Awesome answer, BTW, +1).

Comment: @Rap Feel free to add an answer with a PHP snippet. I'd rather keep the answer about what the question was. And it's pretty trivial to get JSON from PHP, another question if you don't know how to do that.