# Storing JSON signature captured from web in Filemaker Database as Image with php

Tags: php, database, json, html5-canvas, filemaker

I'm using Thomas Bradley's signature pad (http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/) to capture signatures on the web.  It is pushing to a filemaker database as JSON coordinates.

Is there a way to store that JSON coordinates as an image on a Filemaker Database?

Or alternately, is there solution that allows coordinates to be processed as an image for pdf forms?

p.s. I've tried including the php signature-to-image.php file that is on the tutorial page, but it was giving me an error on 58 of the code from that file itself. Not sure if that would have converted the coordinates for storing in database that way.

Similar issue to:
[Extract X&Y coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292260/is-it-possible-to-convert-json-into-a-data-uri-with-php-or-js)

Comment: I don't know if this will work for your particular solution, but consider storing the JSON in a text field and then using a FileMaker webviewer with a data url instead of an image field: http://www.databuzz.com.au/filemaker-web-viewer-and-data-urls/

Comment: Well I found an alternative (http://campsoftware.com/products/shelved-products/qc-signature-capture/  ),using a similar method. Thank you for the suggestion.